# Extracting a streamline from StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

The following function generates a stream plot for `t1` and `t2`.

```
StreamPlot[{k, (-L1 k Sin[t1[t]])/(L2 Sin[t2[t]])},
           {t1[t], -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {t2[t], -Pi/2, Pi/2}
```

I know that each streamline gives me a set of values of `t1` and `t2` for which

```
L1 Cos[t1[t]] + L2 Cos[t2[t]] == rvar
```

is constant, for any values of `L1` and `L2`.

I want to extract the values of a streamline for a particular value of `rvar`. How can I do this?

A solution for the differential equation is also something that can help. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `StreamPoints`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to use `ContourPlot`.  For instance,

```
cp = With[{L1 = 1, L2 = 3, rvar = 3}, 
    ContourPlot[L1 Cos[t1[t]] + L2 Cos[t2[t]] == rvar, 
    {t1[t], -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {t2[t], -Pi/2, Pi/2}, ContourStyle -> Red, 
    FrameLabel -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]]
```

[image]

and the values of the points making up the curve are given by

```
pts = cp[[1, 1]];
```

which can be visualized by

```
ListPlot[pts, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

Comment: Error occurred during execution in v14 version.

Comment: @lotus2019 Apparently, Mathematica internal structure has changed since 2018.  Now, use `pts = cp[[1, 1, 1]];`.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) approach. First, some example parameters:

```
L1 = 1;
L2 = 3;
rvar = 3;
```

Your equation:

```
eqn = L1 Cos[t1[t]]+L2 Cos[t2[t]]==rvar
```

To use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue), we need an initial condition, for which I will use [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance):

```
initial = {t1[t], t2[t]} /. First @ FindInstance[
    {eqn, -π < t1[t] < π, -π < t2[t] < π},
    {t1[t], t2[t]},
    Reals
]
```

> {-π/2, 0}

We have two dependent variables, so we need another ODE. The obvious choice is to parametrize by the arc-length. So, the ODE is:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {
    eqn, t1'[t]^2 + t2'[t]^2 == 1, 
    t1[0] == initial[[1]], t2[0] == initial[[2]],
    WhenEvent[EuclideanDistance[{t1[t],t2[t]}, initial]<.002, end = t; "StopIntegration"]
    },
    {t1, t2},
    {t, 0, 18}
];
```

Probably a better detector of when the solution overlaps itself could be used, but the above did the job.

Visualization:

```
plot = ParametricPlot[Through @ sol @ t, {t, 0, end}]
```

[image]

And a table of values:

```
pts = Table[Through @ sol @ t, {t, Subdivide[0, end, 30]}];
```

Visualization:

```
Show[plot, ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle->Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Error occurred during execution in v14 version.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html). It is meant precisely for this, i.e. numerical solution of differential equations. `StreamPlot` is for plotting and won't be accurate anyway.

Comment: I tried using that, but I'm unable to put it in the correct form i think. How can i put two variables as such?